# Spring Hibernate + AOP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-aop

Help! I'm using Spring+Hibernate and I'm trying to use AOP like this :

```
package ua.i.pustovalov.table;
enter code here

@Aspect
public class Aoprad {

    @Pointcut("execution(* *getAll(..))")
    public void performance() {
    }

    public Aoprad() {

    }

    @Around("performance()")
    public void AfterAndPriv(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    try {

        System.out.println("Open query");
        joinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println("Close query");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}
```

When I try to use my method, it returns null.

```
public class TestDao {

public static void main(String[] args) {
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    new String[] { "applicationContext.xml" }, true);

DaoInterface das = (DaoInterface) context.getBean("dataDao");

System.out.println(das.getAll());

}

<context:annotation-config />

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<context:component-scan base-package="ua.i.pustovalov.*">
</context:component-scan>





<bean id="audience" class="ua.i.pustovalov.table.Aoprad" />


<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="myPointcut"
        expression="execution(* ua.i.pustovalov.maven.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="myPointcut" />
</aop:config>



<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- <tx:method name="get*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true" /> -->
        <tx:method name="getAll*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true" />

    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/homebase</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>root</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value></value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataDao" class="ua.i.putsovalov.dao.DaoStudent">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

**My DAO class**

```
package ua.i.putsovalov.dao;

public class DaoStudent extends HibernateDaoSupport implements DaoInterface {

public DaoStudent() {
}

@Override
protected HibernateTemplate createHibernateTemplate(
    SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
HibernateTemplate result = super
    .createHibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
result.setAllowCreate(true);
return result;
}

@Override
public Student get(int id) {

return (Student) getSession().get(Student.class, id);
}

@Override
public Student get(String text) {
return (Student) getSession().get(Student.class, text);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Collection<Student> getAll() {
return getSession().createCriteria(Student.class).list();
}

}
```

**And interface**

```
public interface DaoInterface {

Student get(int id);

Student get(String text);

Collection<Student> getAll();
}
```

What steps can I take to debug this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's unclear what the problem you are trying to solve is. `das.getAll()` is returning `null`? Any errors?

Comment: Any error! 

a have  <--

Open quary
Hibernate: select this_.id as id0_0_, this_.mark as mark0_0_, this_.name as name0_0_, this_.surname as surname0_0_ from listofstudent this_
Close quary
null  -->

Comment: Error says that getAll() function in DaoStudent class returning null,check data is there in listofstudent  table.

Comment: You are destroying your results because your aspect is wrong. Your aspect returns `void` whereas it should return `Object` and you should return the result of the call to `joinPoint.proceed()`. Every method that matches will return null due to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an around aspect you should always use a method signature that returns `Object` and not `void` and you should always return the result of the call to the `proceed()` method. If you fail to do so every method that is advices by this aspect will return null because there is nothing returned.

```
@Around("performance()")
public Object AfterAndPriv(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
try {
    System.out.println("Open query");
    return joinPoint.proceed();
} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    System.out.println("Close query");
}
}
```